# Trouble with installing pip 8.1.1 from 7.1.2

Tags: python, pip, python-3.3

I'm having an issue with upgrading pip from 7.1.2 to 8.1.1. At first I downloaded Python 3.4 and installed pip from there but then noticed Python 3.5 was there so I downloaded that. When trying to use pip to install selenium it says You are using pip version 7.1.2 however 8.1.1 is available. I do "pip install --upgrade pip" then get an error. See attached screenshot.What do I do? Btw I'm on windows 8.1.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqEL9.png)

Comment: Possibly your existing version of pip is installed by an administrator user, and you are trying to upgrade it as a different (non-admin) user?

Comment: You may need to start your command prompt as an administrator.

Comment: @TomDalton I think you should move your comment into a full answer and adding the command.

Answer (score 4):

Ok. It's working if I run `cmd as an admin` then do

> `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Answer (score 2):

In Mac, I ran:

```
sudo python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Then, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`? if pip is being used, it cannot install itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common question that requires few germane steps to pre-installing other modules in Python.

Depending on the version of your Python (Either the 2.X series or the 3.X series), and the operation system (Window, Ubuntu, etc ), you will need to do the following;

1. Open CMD (Short-Cut: <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> button on the keyboard)
2. Make sure the current directory is the administrator on the hard-drive of the system and your internet connection is available.
           i.e `C:\Users\System_Name PC`
3. Type in the command:

   ```
   Pip install --upgrade pip   
   i.e C:\Users\System_Name PC > pip install --upgrade pip
   ```

and hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key  to activate:
It will uninstall the previous version and install the latest version

4. Restart the system and continue the installation of each python module
   e.g   Pip install dateutil
     Pip install numpy
     Pip install matplotlib

Peradventure you wish to specify the version of the python module dependencies you want to install;

Pip install Django==1.90

It will install the specific version: otherwise if not specified, the latest version of the target module would be installed.